# Symfony Swiftmailer stop sending process to show status

Tags: php, symfony, for-loop, swiftmailer

In our application, for some actions we send out notifications and emails to a rather large number of users (several hundred to thousand). For some purposes we have to send these emails/notifications separately which I did, using a foreach loop. 
For about 200-300 users, that's working fine, but as soon as there are more users to be notified, we get a timeout after a while.

What I was now thinking to do, is redirect to a new page, after e.g. a document is created, and handle the email/notification send out there by sending out let's say 20 emails, then display an update like "20 out of xxx emails/notifications have been sent out", then continue sending the next 20, displaying an update and so on.

Is there any body who already did something like this or has ideas on that?
Here is my code so far:

```
       {
    document gets created...
              $em->persist($document);
              $em->flush();

              $this->addFlash(
                'success',
                'Your document has been created!'
                );

              return $this->redirectToRoute('documentBundle_document_send_notifications',  array('id' => strtok($document->getId(), '_')));

            }

      /**
    * @Route("/document/sendNotifications/{id}", name="documentBundle_document_send_notifications", requirements={"id" = "\d+"})
    */
    public function sendDocumentNotifications($id){
      $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
      $document = $em->getRepository('DocumentBundle:Document')->findOneById($id);
      $statusRepository = $em->getRepository('DocumentBundle:Status');

      /*
      * NOTIFICATION MANAGEMENT
      */

      //Users
      $user = $em->getRepository('UserBundle:User');
      $user = $user->findByDocumentAgency($user, $document);
      $users = array_unique($user->getResult());

 if(count($users)>0){
        /*
        * SEND NOTIFICATION
        */
        foreach ($users as $user){
          $manager = $this->get('mgilet.notification');
          $notif = $manager->generateNotification('A Document has been created!');
          $manager->addNotification($user, $notif);
        }

        /*
        * SEND EMAIL
        */

       foreach ($users as $user){
            $recipient = $user->getEmail();
            $this->get('MailerHelper')->sendMessage($recipient,...);
          }
        }
      }
        return $this->redirectToRoute('documentBundle_document_list');
    }
```

**EDIT**

added a console command to run as a background process

```
/**
* @Route("/document/sendNotifications/{id}", name="documentBundle_document_send_notifications", requirements={"id" = "\d+"})
*/
public function sendDocumentNotifications($id){
  $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
  $document = $em->getRepository('DocumentBundle:Document')->findOneById($id);
  $process = new Process('php app/console app:send-notifications', $id );
  $process->run();

  dump($process);

  return $this->redirectToRoute('documentBundle_document_bulkDeactivate');


}
```

when dumping the process, I get the correct commandLine and the input is the correct document Id, but it says:

```
   Process {#1539 ▼
  -callback: null
  -commandline: "php app/console app:send-notifications"
  -cwd: "/srv/http/sp/web"
  -env: null
  -input: "320"
  -starttime: 1511378616.9664
  -lastOutputTime: 1511378616.9852
  -timeout: 60.0
  -idleTimeout: null
  -options: array:2 [▼
    "suppress_errors" => true
    "binary_pipes" => true
  ]
  -exitcode: 1
  -fallbackStatus: []
  -processInformation: array:8 [▼
    "command" => "php app/console app:send-notifications"
    "pid" => 29887
    "running" => false
    "signaled" => false
    "stopped" => false
    "exitcode" => 1
    "termsig" => 0
    "stopsig" => 0
```

I then tried it with 
**$process->mustRun()** and gut the following error:

> > The command "php app/console app:send-notifications" failed.
>
> Exit Code: 1(General error)
>
> Working directory: /srv/http/sp/web
>
> Output:
>   ================ Could not open input file: app/console
>
> ## Error Output:
>
> 500 Internal Server Error - ProcessFailedException

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR: to prevent time-outs, offload your process to a background process.

## First step: use a spool

A quick win would be [to Spool Emails](https://symfony.com/doc/current/email/spool.html):

> When you are using the SwiftmailerBundle to send an email from a
>   Symfony application, it will default to sending the email immediately.
>   You may, however, want to avoid the performance hit of the
>   communication between Swift Mailer and the email transport, which
>   could cause the user to wait for the next page to load while the email
>   is sending.

The actual mails will be sent by a command line script:
`php bin/console swiftmailer:spool:send --env=prod`.

## Next step: create a command that handles notifications

Learn how to [create a console command](https://symfony.com/doc/3.3/console.html). Something like this (not tested, just as an example):

```
class NotificationCommand extends ContainerAwareCommand
{

    protected function configure()
    {
        $this
            // the name of the command (the part after "bin/console")
            ->setName('app:send-notifications')

            // the short description shown while running "php bin/console list"
            ->setDescription('Send notifications to information users about a new document.')

            ->addArgument('document', InputArgument::REQUIRED, 'The ID of the new document.')

        ;
    }

    public function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
    {
          $em = $this->getContainer()->get('doctrine')->getManager();
          $document = $em->getRepository('DocumentBundle:Document')->findOneById($input->getArgument('document'));
          $statusRepository = $em->getRepository('DocumentBundle:Status');

          /*
          * NOTIFICATION MANAGEMENT
          */

          //Users
          $user = $em->getRepository('UserBundle:User');
          $user = $user->findByDocumentAgency($user, $document);
          $users = array_unique($user->getResult());

        if(count($users)>0){
            /*
            * SEND NOTIFICATION
            */
            foreach ($users as $user){
              $manager = $this->get('mgilet.notification');
              $notif = $manager->generateNotification('A Document has been created!');
              $manager->addNotification($user, $notif);
            }

            /*
            * SEND EMAIL
            */

           foreach ($users as $user){
                $recipient = $user->getEmail();
                $this->get('MailerHelper')->sendMessage($recipient,...);
              }
            }
          }
    }
}
```

To execute this, run `bin/console app:send-notifications 1` on your command line.

### Schedule your command

I guess you don't want to log into the server manually to send the notifications, so instead you can create a general 'send notifications if needed' command that can scheduled by a cron job.

As a next step you can take a look at a way to queue your commands. Take [JMSJobQueueBundle](https://jmsyst.com/bundles/JMSJobQueueBundle/master/installation) for example.

#### Bonus tip: start by making your controllers thinner

Try to make your controllers thinner. Read [this](http://richardmiller.co.uk/2012/10/31/symfony2-trimming-fat-from-controllers/) old, but still interesting blog. If you create services and call them from the controller (instead of having a *fat* controller), the 'refactoring' job of removing code from controller to background job (and maybe visa versa) is much easier.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer! Truth is, my emails already get spooled but I still get the timeout. So unfortunately that doesn't help :/

Comment: Then you'll have to offload it to a background job. That's what I did when I faced the same problem, and after implementing a job scheduler (JMSJobQueueBundle in my case, but there are many more options) I offloaded many more 'expensive' tasks from the controller. That's why you should keep your controllers *thin* and create services: that makes moving actions from the Controller to a Command very easy.

Comment: thank you, I added a command to run it as a background process. but it seems as if it's not executing the process..

I added my code , can you see any mistakes?

Comment: That won't work. If you run a command in your controller, it isn't a background process anymore. Please read https://symfony.com/doc/3.3/console.html and https://jmsyst.com/bundles/JMSJobQueueBundle/master/installation

Comment: ‘new Process‘ will execute a command in your controller, but that's what you don't want.